# "Awesome Font" Not Displaying

Tags: font-awesome

I have recently moved my website from the **ROOT** folder to a **SUB** folder. Since I have done this my "Awesome Font" is not displaying in my browsers.

**The missed font is showing the errors:**

My Header (on the left, missing currencies.

My Footer (copyright text not showing, resulting in the payment methods dropping bellow the footer).

My website can be found here: ----

Comment: Check the access permissions for the folders. Check if you updated all paths correctly.

Comment: The only files I have updated is my 2 .Config files. Btw, I am new to web design, so please try to explain more briefly to me. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a path problem, most likely.
You probably changed the structure of directories, if it used to work before this change.

Try loading Awesome-Font from CDN server and see if it works, if so you have to change your path to the font awesome directory.

Comment: How do I change the path? What files do I need to access? I use open cart so editing the script is not something I am too familiar with unless given instructions.

Comment: "catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/font-awesome.min.css" - This is the path you are trying to load Font-Awesome from your html site, in you <head> section. Check if the file and directories really exist. Try to load it from here - http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Here is the script in my header for the font-awesome.min.css :

 */@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'),url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.1.0') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}

Comment: In your site .html file I can see you are referring Awesome-font.css to a specific location as I wrote above. Try and see if it is correct and that the file really exist. Also what you written above is creating new font-family based on the urls you provided there, it might not work, depending on your input. You should try and update the link I wrote you earlier instead of the absolute path in your local project (Again, at your main/index .html in your <head> section).

Comment: Do you mean I need to edit the code BELLOW and update the path? The code was found in my header.tpl, if that is the file you mean? I am very sorry, I am only at a beginners level here, and I do not fully understand.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/responsive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/cloud-zoom.css" />

Comment: I tried to put /Aystot/ before catalog, but it still didn't work. The reason I put /Aystot/ before is because that is my Sub folder I just added?

Comment: I want you to change this - <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/font-awesome.min.css" /> to this - <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css /> and check if it works now.

Comment: Just done that, and it still hasn't worked. So just to make sure I did exactly as you said. I updated the header.tpl header section to:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.c‌​ss />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/responsive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/crypto/stylesheet/cloud-zoom.css" />

Comment: Try adding http: just before the // in the href.

Comment: Still no luck with above. Thanks for trying btw, I really appreciate your time. And I apologise for the lack of my knowledge.

Comment: Are you sure it worked before ? And the only thing changed was the directory's location ?

Comment: Yes, it definitely worked. For almost a month since I created my website. Anything else I am missing? I moved all my files from ROOT to SUB in a folder called Aystot. I then updated my 2 .Config files with the new location. Anything else I should have updated? I have heard about the  .htaccess file Rewritebase rule, is this something I am missing or is it not needed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Open Cart platform but in all honesty, font awesome is an easy tool to use. You only need to refer to the .css in the page you want to insert it and use it like demonstrated in the examples on their website. Ex: <i class=" what icon you want here"></i>. I might been missing something else here too.

Comment: I think it is something to do with my .htaccess file. As I am playing around with it, it is showing SOME missing features I lost, but not all. I think I have seriously messed up my .htaccess file. I don't know how they work, but if I deleted that file, would it re-create the file without causing too much damage?

Comment: It shows in my .htaccess file, under my Aystot sub directory, information about another sub directory I have, it sounds wrong to me?                   # Begin default subdomain redirect #
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nibbleicious.tk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nibbleicious.tk/$1 [R=permanent,L]


# End default subdomain redirect #


When I remove all of that, some of my lost features show.

Comment: I know that in Wordpress if you have a missing or corrupted .htaccess file you can delete it and recreate it when you save your permalinks settings once again. I'm not sure how to do that using Open Cart. It might be the same but not sure.

Comment: I think I am going to face to music. Too complicated for me to see too so I am going to re-create the whole website tomorrow, but this time, I will START the creation of it already under the SUB, therefore I won't get no complications when trying to move location. I'd like to say though, thanks a lot for helping me I really appreciate that.

Comment: No problem, but I would recommend trying to see if it's really the .htaccess file giving you trouble with permissions or it is messed up, maybe trying to create it ftom scratch with basic configurations or regenerate it somehow. Anyway, good luck solving your problem.